# How to make html form to submit to X page first wait for a while and submit to another Y page because Y page needs processed data of X page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

// How do I make this javascript to submit to y.php first and wait a while until it is processed and submit to x.php

```
function validatedaily()
{
    form=document.getElementById('myform');
    form.action='y.php';
    form.submit();
    form.action='x.php';
    form.submit();
}
```

Comment: you have a design problem, i think. but if you insist that way, just use javascript's `setTimeout` function.

Comment: Try use jQuery's post functions for this. $.post("y.php", data, function(result){
          console.log(result.status);
          // post again
        
        });

Comment: @marmeladze setTimeout won't solve the problem in this case as you need to set the duration of delay beforehand (and you can't know how long the form submit will be processing).

Do you need to retrieve some data from the y.php or not?
In any case you can do that with $.post() function (if you are using jQuery) and then use the .done() on it to call the secont $.post()

Answer (score 1):

try with this:

**on jQuery**

> You can use `$.ajax()` as `jQuery.ajax()`. Learn about this API [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

```
$.ajax({
    url     :   'x.php',
    type    :   'get',
    dataType:   'json'
    success :   function(xResponse){
        $.ajax({
            url     :   'y.php',
            type    :   'get',
            dataType:   'json'
            success :   function(yResponse){

            }
        });
    }
});
```

**on Angular:**

> You can use `$http.get()`, `$http.post`, `$http.put()`, etc.  Learn about this API [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

```
$http({
    method  :   'GET',
    url     :   'x.php'
}).then(function(xResponse){
    // use xResponse.data to get response data
    $http({
        method  :   'GET',
        url     :   'y.php'
    }).then(function(yResponse){
        // use yResponse.data to get response data
    })
})
```

**"Simple" XHR(pure javascript):**

> This method work on IE6+ and all Chrome, Chromium, Firefox and Safari versions. Learn about [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/XMLHttpRequest) API, [MSXML2.XmlHttp.xx API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535874(v=vs.85).aspx) and [Microsoft.XmlHttp](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537505(v=vs.85).aspx)

```
var ajax = {};
// prepare xhr api
ajax.x = function () {
    var xhr;
    if (typeof XMLHttpRequest !== 'undefined') return new XMLHttpRequest();
    // API's
    var versions = [
        "MSXML2.XmlHttp.6.0",
        "MSXML2.XmlHttp.5.0",
        "MSXML2.XmlHttp.4.0",
        "MSXML2.XmlHttp.3.0",
        "MSXML2.XmlHttp.2.0",
        "Microsoft.XmlHttp"
    ];
    for (var i = 0; i < versions.length; i++) {
        try {
            xhr = new ActiveXObject(versions[i]);
            break;
        } catch (e) {
        }
    }
    return xhr;
};
// function to send
ajax.send = function (url, callback, method, data, async) {
    if (async === undefined) async = true;
    var xhr = ajax.x();
    xhr.open(method, url, async);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) callback(xhr.responseText)
    };
    if (method == 'POST') xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.send(data)
};

// you can use like this
ajax.send('x.php', function(xResponse) {
    // console.log( xResponse );
    ajax.send('y.php', function (yResponse) {
        // console.log( yResponse )
    }, 'GET')
}, 'GET')
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try this

```
 function validatedaily()
{
  form=document.getElementById('myform');
  form.action='y.php';

 if(form.submit()){
    form.action='x.php';
    form.submit();
  }


}
```

also try using ajax

```
$.ajax({url: "x.php", async:false, success: function(result){                another(result); }}); function another(result){ $.ajax({url: "y.php",success: function(result){ console.log(result); }}); }
```

Comment: try using sync ajax

Comment: $.ajax({url: "x.php", async:false, success: function(result){
       
    }});

Comment: $.ajax({url: "x.php", async:false, success: function(result){     //here call a function which contains another ajax        another(result);                               }});                                                                                                                               function another(result){ $.ajax({url: "y.php",success: function(result){     //console.log(result); }}); }